# is.numeric and is.integer give unexpected results

Tags: r

When querying my XML-database, in essence the result comes as a vector with one element per row.

```
input <- c("[1, 1.05e0, true(), \"1\", false()]", "[2, 4.0e0, true(), \"8\", true()]" more rows)
```

After converting each element to a list, it is easy to add each element from the vector as a row to a dataframe. The only that remains then is to convert each column to the proper type. My problem is that I don't know how to determine the type for each column.
I start by creating a template based on the first element from the input.

```
> template <- input[[1]] %>% str_replace_all("[\\[\\]]", "") %>% str_replace_all(", ", ",") %>%
+   str_replace_all("\"", "'") %>% strsplit(",") %>% .[[1]]
> template
[1] "1"       "1.05e0"  "true()"  "'1'"     "false()"
```

I then use this template to determine the column-type.

```
test_type <- function(template) {
  Bools <- which(template %in% c("true", "true()", "false", "false()"))
  NonBools <- setdiff(1:length(template), Bools)
  cat("Bools", "\n")
  for (i in Bools) {
    cat(i, "\n")
  }
  cat("NonBools", "\n")
  for (i in NonBools) {
    if (is.numeric(template[[i]])) { Type <- "Num"}
    else if (is.integer(template[[i]])) {Type <- "Int"}
    else {Type <- "Char"}
    cat(i, template[i], Type, "\n", sep = " ")
  }
}

> test_type(template)
Bools 
3 
5 
NonBools 
1 1 Char 
2 1.05e0 Char 
4 '1' Char
```

As you can see my function does not return the wright type. `is.numeric(template[[1]])` returns FALSE but `as.numeric(template[[1]])` returns `1`. `as.numeric(template[[4]])` returns `NA`

Can someone explain why is.numeric() returns the wrong answer? How can I determine the correct type?

Ben

Comment: which answer is wrong? The returned values seem correct to me. "1" is a character, but convertable to numeric (as 1) but " '1' " is not convertible to numeric as it has the extra quote marks. Also, all integers are numeric, so if you want to test for integer, that test has to come before the numeric test

Comment: The documentation tells that is.numeric() is is a more general test of an object being interpretable as numbers. This should apply to both 1 and 2. template[4] (" '1' ") is not interpretable as a number so that answer is correct (but in my example this is not explicitly tested). The test should return "Int", "Num", "Char" for elements 1, 2 and 4. (And thx for the advice on swapping the Num and the Int-test)

Comment: one small note, in R the class for TRUE/FALSE is called logical, not boolean (though they are the same thing). Also, R requires TRUE/FALSE to be uppercase and have no brackets (brackets imply they are a function, which they are not)

Answer (score 1):

We can correct OP's function by using:

```
test_type <- function(template) {

  Bools <- which(template %in% c("true", "true()", "false", "false()"))
  NonBools <- setdiff(1:length(template), Bools)
  cat("Bools", "\n")
  for (i in Bools) {
    cat(i, "\n")
 }
  cat("NonBools", "\n")
  for (i in NonBools) {
     num <- as.numeric(template[i])
     if (!is.na(num) && num %% 1 != 0)  Type <- "Num"
     else if (!is.na(num) && num %% 1 == 0) Type <- "Int"
     else Type <- "Char"
     cat(i, template[i], Type, "\n", sep = " ")
   }
}


suppressWarnings(test_type(template))

#Bools 
#3 
#5 
#NonBools 
#1 1 Int 
#2 1.05e0 Num 
#4 '1' Char
```

Points to note :

- When we check for `is.numeric(template[[i]])`, `template[[i]]` is still character and has not changed its class. So `is.numeric` would always fail.
- Integers satisfy `as.numeric` test. Check `class(1L)` and `is.numeric(1L)`. So we need some other tests to check for integers.
- We use here `num %% 1 == 0` to test for integers.

Comment: At one moment, I tried if !is.na(as.numeric(template[i])) could be used but I stopped because I couldn't get rid of the warnings. This is much nicer!
And thnax for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it using `case_when` from the `dplyr` package:

```
template <- c("1", "1.05e0", "true()", "'1'", "false()")

dplyr::case_when(
  tolower(template) %in% c('true', 'false', 'true()', 'false()')  ~ 'Boolean',
  as.integer(template) == template ~ 'Integer',
  !is.na(as.numeric(template)) ~ 'Numeric',
  TRUE ~ 'Character')

#  "Integer"   "Numeric"   "Boolean"   "Character" "Boolean"
```

This could also be done with `if/else` statements, but I think the `case_when` syntax is nicer.

I also added in the `tolower()` for the template to make sure `TRUE` and `FALSE` are also counted as boolean

**Edit:**

The integer one was not working, so now do it a different way